# Passing received `.csv` file from Node js to some other server

Tags: node.js, forms

I am trying to send a `.csv` file from node js to another server

```
uploadCSVData = async(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: any
):Promise<any> =>{
    const csvForm = new FormData();
    csvForm.append('upload', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path));
    console.log(csvForm);
    const options = {
         upload: csvForm,
         headers: {
                    authorization: req.headers.svctoken,
                    'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
         json: true
    };
    const response = await this.postSvc.exec(
                ['https://come/svc', `someAPI?id=${req.body.acntID}`]
                .join('/'),
                options
        );

return res.status(200).json(response.body);
}
```

I can see error as :

> "no multipart boundary param in Content-Type"

How to send this `req.file` to another server which expects as `'multipart/form-data'`

**I dont think its a good idea to add `boundary` explicitly when I am using `form-data`**

The `csvForm` is below in console log:

```
FormData {
  _overheadLength: 167,
  _valueLength: 0,
  _valuesToMeasure:
   [ ReadStream {
       _readableState: [ReadableState],
       readable: true,
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 3,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       path: 'uploads\\1533537127411_sample1.csv',
       fd: null,
       flags: 'r',
       mode: 438,
       start: undefined,
       end: Infinity,
       autoClose: true,
       pos: undefined,
       bytesRead: 0,
       closed: false,
       emit: [Function] } ],
  writable: false,
  readable: true,
  dataSize: 0,
  maxDataSize: 2097152,
  pauseStreams: true,
  _released: false,
  _streams:
   [ '----------------------------481765298048352594095608\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="1533537127411_sample1.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n',
     DelayedStream {
       source: [ReadStream],
       dataSize: 0,
       maxDataSize: Infinity,
       pauseStream: true,
       _maxDataSizeExceeded: false,
       _released: false,
       _bufferedEvents: [Array],
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 1 },
     [Function: bound ] ],
  _currentStream: null,
  _boundary: '--------------------------481765298048352594095608' }
```

#### Another approach

I tried passing file directly rather than creating FormData() like:

```
        const options = {
                upload: req.file,
                headers: {
                    authorization: req.headers.svctoken,
                    'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                json: true
        };
```

but the error is still there

Comment: What do you use to send file to another server? How about using axios? https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/789

Comment: You could solve this just defining a boundary parameter in the header, like boundary=myBoundary , read this https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: hey Samuel, did you try using the submit method? what modules are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648693/noobtw on this, it's not clear what library you're using to make the request. With that said, it looks like you may be using https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data to handle the form data.

Looking at the documentation for that module, it doesn't appear that there's a need to explicitly add the `Content-Type` header when making the request. Simply use the `submit` method of your `form` instance to send the data. Note that the examples below are sourced from the form-data modules documentation:

```
csvForm.submit({
  host: 'example.com',
  path: '/your-path',
  headers: { authorization: req.headers.svctoken }
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

For passing the file with formData using the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) library, you can do the following:

```
const formData = {
  my_field: 'my_value',
  upload: fs.createReadStream(req.file.path),
};


request.post({url:'https://yourservice.com/upload', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

( from the `form-data` [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) )

```
In Node.js environment you need to set boundary in the header field 'Content-Type' by calling method `getHeaders`
```

so your `Content-type` should be dynamically generated from `csvForm.getHeaders()` rather than being manually set to `multipart/form-data`. This will result in the form boundary being included in the content type as well ex.

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------205082924173531574135800'
```